# Deleting records via rails has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My model schema:

Poll

```
has_many :questions
has_many :responses :through => :questions
```

Question

```
belongs_to :poll
has_many :responses
```

Response

```
belongs_to :question
```

**Problem** when I try to run `@poll.responses.delete_all` or `clear` or `destroy_all` I get this error:

`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association 'Poll#responses' because the source reflection class 'Response' is associated to 'Question' via :has_many.`

Update: Still not sure why this is happening, but here's a workaround: 

`@poll.responses.each(&:destroy)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Poll.first.responses.each(&:destroy)
```

Delete only works when the association on the join model is `:belongs_to`.

Comment: This works! Leaving it open for a bit to see if anyone can explain the weird error.

Comment: The error is saying that you can't modify the Poll#records collection directly through Poll since Question :has_many :polls. The collection is read-only instead.

Comment: The Join model that connects Poll and Responses is Question. Since Question has a 'has_many' relation with Response, the collection of Responses that are retrieved when you do '@poll.responses' is Read-only (as per the docs of the :through clause) and so can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use destroy_all, it will work best with relations.

```
@poll.responses.destroy_all
```

Comment: I get the same error... also the docs recommend using delete when there are many items to avoid triggering validations/callbacks